# Kafka Streams - Fields in the Custom object changing to null while doing Aggregation

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've written a simple Kafka Stream processor code to

1. Read messages as stream from a topic with <K, V> as <String, String>
2. Convert the value in the message from String to a Custom Object <String, Object> using mapValues() method
3. Use Window function to aggregate the statistics of the Objects for a particular time interval

**Sample Message**

> {"coiRequestGuid":"xxxx","accountId":1122132,"companyName":"xxxx","existingPolicyCoverageLimit":1000000,"isChangeRequested":true,"newlyRequestedPolicyCoverageLimit":200000,"isNewRecipient":false,"newRecipientGuid":null,"existingRecipientId":11111,"recipientName":"xxxx","recipientEmail":"xxxxx"}

Here is my code

```
import com.da.app.data.model.PolicyChangeRequest;
import com.da.app.data.model.PolicyChangeRequestStats;
import com.da.app.data.serde.JsonDeserializer;
import com.da.app.data.serde.JsonSerializer;
import com.da.app.data.serde.WrapperSerde;
import com.da.app.system.util.ConfigUtil;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.WindowStore;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PolicyChangeReqStreamProcessor {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PolicyChangeReqStreamProcessor.class);
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "stream-window-play1";
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static Properties properties = ConfigUtil.loadProperty();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Policy Limit Change Stats Generator");
        Properties streamProperties = getStreamProperties();
        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> source = streamsBuilder.stream(TOPIC_NAME,
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        source
                .filter((key, value) -> isValidEvent(value))
                //Converting the request json to PolicyChangeRequest object
                .mapValues(PolicyChangeReqStreamProcessor::convertPolicyChangeReqJsonToObj)

                //Mapping all events to a single key in order to group all the events
                .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>("key", value))

                // Grouping by key
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new PolicyChangeRequestSerde()))
                //Creating a Tumbling window of 5 secs (for Testing)
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).advanceBy(Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
                // Aggregating the PolicyChangeRequest events to a
                // PolicyChangeRequestStats object
                .<PolicyChangeRequestStats>aggregate(PolicyChangeRequestStats::new,
                        (k, v, policyStats) -> policyStats.add(v),
                        Materialized.<String, PolicyChangeRequestStats, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as
                                ("policy-change-aggregates")
                                .withValueSerde(new PolicyChangeRequestStatsSerde()))
                //Converting KTable to KStream
                .toStream()
                .foreach((key, value) -> logger.info(key.window().startTime() + "----" + key.window().endTime() + "  :: " + value));


        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), streamProperties);
        logger.info("Started the stream");
        kafkaStreams.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(kafkaStreams::close));
    }

    private static PolicyChangeRequest convertPolicyChangeReqJsonToObj(String policyChangeReq) {
        JSONObject policyChangeReqJson = new JSONObject(policyChangeReq);
        PolicyChangeRequest policyChangeRequest = new PolicyChangeRequest(policyChangeReqJson);

//            return mapper.readValue(value, PolicyChangeRequest.class);
        return policyChangeRequest;
    }

    private static boolean isValidEvent(String value) {
        //TODO: Message Validation

        return true;
    }

    private static Properties getStreamProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "policy-change-stats-gen");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, properties.getProperty("kafka.bootstrap.servers"));
        props.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "stream-window-play1");

        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        return props;
    }


    public static final class PolicyChangeRequestStatsSerde extends WrapperSerde<PolicyChangeRequestStats> {
        PolicyChangeRequestStatsSerde() {
            super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(PolicyChangeRequestStats.class));
        }
    }

    public static final class PolicyChangeRequestSerde extends WrapperSerde<PolicyChangeRequest> {
        PolicyChangeRequestSerde() {
            super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>(PolicyChangeRequest.class));
        }
    }

}
```

`isValidEvent` -  returns true

`.mapValues(PolicyChangeReqStreamProcessor::convertPolicyChangeReqJsonToObj)` - This will convert the incoming json string to a PolicyChangeRequest object

Till the operation `map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>("key", value))`, the Custom Object - PolicyChangeRequest is fine as per the incoming message (I've tested by printing the stream there).

But after going into the **Groupby** and **aggregate** operation, the Custom Object got changed as

> PolicyChangeRequest{coiRequestGuid='null', accountId='null', companyName='null', existingPolicyCoverageLimit=null, isChangeRequested=null, newlyRequestedPolicyCoverageLimit=null, isNewRecipient=null, newRecipientGuid='null', existingRecipientId='null', recipientName='null', recipientEmail='null'}

I found the above value by putting a log statement inside the `policyStats.add(v)` method i've called inside the aggregate method.

The add method is in the PolicyChangeRequestStats class

```
    public PolicyChangeRequestStats add(PolicyChangeRequest policyChangeRequest) {
        System.out.println("Incoming req:   " + policyChangeRequest);
        //Incrementing the Policy limit change request count
        this.policyLimitChangeRequests++;

        //Adding the Increased policy limit coverage to the existing increasedPolicyLimitCoverage
        this.increasedPolicyLimitCoverage +=
                (policyChangeRequest.getNewlyRequestedPolicyCoverageLimit() -
                        policyChangeRequest.getExistingPolicyCoverageLimit());

        return this;
    }
```

I'm getting **NullPointerException** in the line where I'm adding the `policyChangeRequest.getNewlyRequestedPolicyCoverageLimit() - policyChangeRequest.getExistingPolicyCoverageLimit()` as the values were null in the PolicyChangeRequest object

I've provided the valid Serde classes for the key and Value while doing groupBy `.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new PolicyChangeRequestSerde()))`.

For Serialization and Desrialization I used Gson.

But I can't able to get the PolicyChangeRequest object as is before it was sent to the grouping operation.

I'm new to kafka Streams and I'm not sure whether I missed anything or whether the process I'm doing is correct or not.

Can anyone guide me here?